# Append variables to url after form submit

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I have this Landing Page that I need to pre-populate with form values after it is submitted. Essentially in the end I have to make the url look like this...

http://example.com/r.php?sid=xx&pub=xxxxx&c1=&c2=&c3=&append=1&firstname=Test&lastname=Smith&address=2211+Commerce+St.&city=Dallas&state=TX&zipcode=75080&email=test@test.com

What I currently have now for the form is...

```
<form name="regForm" method="get" action="http://example.com/r.php?sid=xx&pub=xxxx&c1=&c2=&c3=&append=1">
    <input id="firstname" class="text" type="text" name="firstname"/><br>
    <input id="lastname" class="text" type="text" name="lastname" /><br>
    <input id="email" class="text" type="text"  name="email" /><br>
    <input id="address" class="text" type="text" /><br>
    <input id="city" class="text" type="text"/><br>
    <input id="zipcode" class="text" type="text" maxlength="5" name="zipcode" /><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send Me My FREE List" id="submitBtn2"/>
</form>
```

How do i create that URL above after the form is submitted? I have been racking my brain all day on this and can't figure it out, i feel like im close.

thanks for the help!

Comment: x*x.com? better use example.com

Comment: I'm now following. You've got `method="get"` set, so it should just work as-is. What url *do* you get when you submit?

Comment: Or do you mean you want to fill the values using the `value` attribute like this? `<input id="firstname" class="text" type="text" name="firstname" value="Test"/>`

Comment: @BenLee i get this "example.com/r.php?firstname=D&lastname=M&email=dave%40eternalnyc.com&state=&zipcode=89078&look=Single+Family+Home "

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Include the extra parameters as hidden form fields instead of inline query parameters:

```
<form name="regForm" method="get" action="http://example.com/r.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="sid" value="xx" />
    <input type="hidden" name="pub" value="xxxx" />
    <input type="hidden" name="c1" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="c2" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="c3" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="append" value="1" />

    <input id="firstname" class="text" type="text" name="firstname"/><br>
    <input id="lastname" class="text" type="text" name="lastname" /><br>
    <input id="email" class="text" type="text"  name="email" /><br>
    <input id="address" class="text" type="text" /><br>
    <input id="city" class="text" type="text"/><br>
    <input id="zipcode" class="text" type="text" maxlength="5" name="zipcode" /><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send Me My FREE List" id="submitBtn2"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the input field get variables are causing your url get variables to be truncated, put all your url parameters as hidden values.

```
<input id="pub" type="hidden" name="pub" value=""/>
<input id="sid" type="hidden" name="sid" value=""/>
```

Comment: the problem with this is that the sid and pub variables need to be defined (it is an affiliate link)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you like the URL that it generates except that you're missing the sid, pub, c1, c2, c3, and append variables.  If so, just make hidden inputs like this:

```
<form id="regForm" ...>
  <input id="sid" name="sid" value="" type="hidden" />
  <input id="pub" name="pub" value="" type="hidden" />
  ...
</form>
```

If you know the values while you're creating the form, then you can do it on the server side.  If you don't, then assuming you're using jQuery, you will have to do something like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#regForm').submit(function () {
    $('#sid').val('myNewSidValue');
    $('#pub').val('myNewPubValue');
    ...
  });
});
```